# how to try execute repeatly if command.ExecuteNonQuery() fails

Tags: t-sql, ado.net, sql-server-2008-express

how to try execute repeatly if command.ExecuteNonQuery() fails?

Comment: It would help to know what you mean by failure.  A timeout perhaps?  Are you looking for a specific exception to be thrown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
bool executed = false;
while (!executed)
{
    try
    {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        executed = true;
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

You can add some more conditions like a timer or a counter but this does not seem to be a good idea. You should probably come up with a better recovery scenario.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I can think is:

```
while(true) {
    try {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        break;
    } catch(SqlException ex) { }
}
```

You should anyway put some extra control code in the catch block to prevent an infinite loop and/or to log the error.